# Getting Round Up Error in Less Than/Greater Than When Using "0.5"

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having a heck of a time with this. I'm trying to get it to convert the birthdate to age, then based on age, eventually I'll be designating certain questions that are shown in a form based on the age. This is the first part I started working on for now, and I can't seem to figure out why it's always coming to show 0-6 months even though it should be 7-12 months.

EDITED BECAUSE I SCREWED UP THE CODE I HAD PASTED @_@.

The code I used for the birthdate keeps making it 0 or something. I'm not certain.

Could it be something with rounding or not being able to use "0.5"?

```
<?php

  $birthDate = "2/17/2015";
  $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
  $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md")
? ((date("Y") - $birthDate[2]) - 1)
: (date("Y") - $birthDate[2]));

if($age <= 0.5){               
    echo "0-6 Months";
}
elseif($age > 0.5 && $age < 1) {                
    echo "7-12 Months Old"; 
}
elseif($age >= 1 && $age < 3) {                 
    echo "1-2 Years Old";   
}    
elseif($age >= 2 && $age < 5) {                 
    echo "2-4 Years";                    
} 
elseif($age >= 1 && $age < 3) {                 
    echo "5-8 Years Old";   
}
elseif($age >= 2 && $age < 5) {                 
    echo "9-11 Years";                   
} 
elseif($age >= 1 && $age < 3) {                 
    echo "12-17 Years Old"; 
}
elseif ($age >= 18 && $age < 65) {              
    echo "Adult";                
} 
elseif ($age >= 65){               
    echo "Senior";               
} 
else {               
    echo "Whoops!";
}

echo "</br></br>";
```

Comment: tested 0.5, 0-6 months returned (http://codepad.viper-7.com/bbGLHS). `echo $age`

Comment: ... 0.5 should be 0-6 NOT 7-12. "**<=**" less than OR EQUAL

Comment: I think the problem is that the birthdate code is not providing decimal results, and is giving whole numbers. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score -1):

You're working way too hard at this. You need the `DateTime` class. Then you can do something like this:

```
$birthDate = new DateTime("2/17/2015");
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $birthDate->diff($now);
echo $interval->format('%y years and %a days'); // 0 years and 331 days

$years = $interval->format('%y');
$days = $interval->format('%a');

if ($years == 0) {
    echo ($days < 183) ? '0-6 months' : '7-12 months';
}
else {
    switch ($years) {
        case < 3:
            echo '1-2 years old';
        case < 5:
            echo '2-4 years old';
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: does not really mach his results

Comment: @Dagon I respectfully disagree

Comment: nothing wrong with editing it to fix a wrong answer, just dont lie about it

Comment: @Dagon I disagree with your assessment of the original answer as "wrong" and I don't appreciate being called a liar. After reviewing my original answer I deemed it to be incomplete, so I appended some additional code.

Comment: I am kinda new at this and the switch code isn't exactly working. What's the proper way to input each case? It's giving me errors with the "<"